# MySQL - adding 1 to column with name in backticks

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble adding 1 to a column value in MySQL.  I've used backticks on the column name and value isn't incrementing.  Here is my query:

```
$update = $connectdb->prepare("UPDATE `strings` SET posted=posted, `response-comment`=`response-comment` + 1 WHERE `id`=?");
$update->execute(array($id));
```

Why isn't my query working?  The value `$id` is correct, the column `response-comment` should increase by 1.

Comment: Can you post the schema of your table?

Comment: it's a normal table, it has no constraints.  I tried updating another column and it worked.   I think it has something to do with the dash in the column name, which is why i used backticks.

Comment: This normally works.The question is now what happens to the prepared query after binding the parameters to it.

Comment: I recommend echoing the number of affected rows (`PDOStatement::rowCount()` or `mysqli_stmt::$affected_rows`) to make sure it's really updating a nonzero number of rows. Either `$id` is wrong or `response-comment` is already at MAXINT or something. Also examine warnings.

Comment: Or you are updating the table in one database, and then confirming the data in a different database with the same table name.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for your SQL statement (presuming `strings` is the name of your table:

```
UPDATE `strings` SET `response-comment`=`response-comment` + 1 WHERE `id`=?
```

Comment: I agree with you the posted=posted in the update query looks quite strange and just a waste of time and resources. But this should not affect the operation of the query.

Comment: i tried this and still doesn't update, this should work i don't see any problem.

Comment: Does the statement work if you execute it directly rather than executing it via PHP? If so, that might indicate there's something awry in the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with tick marks
If improperly coded you can end up with quotes which is going to transform you integer value into a string and thus changing the behavior of your request.
Have you tried with out `, just`response-comment = response-comment + 1`